# Is my translation wrong? I am not sure about どれほどいたか

Tags: translation

Someone asked this question:

> 最近、男性からcmを見て堀北真希と顔の系統一緒‼ 化粧頑張ったらあそこまでいけるよと言われたのですがこれはほめられてるんでしょうか？
>
> 大変有難い話ですが私が
>
> 似てないですよと言ったら系統が一緒と返されました…
>
> どうでもいいと思いますがご回答御願いします。

This was the reply they got:

> それは超ベタ褒めです可愛いの代名詞ですし結婚して
>
> 泣いた男性がドレほどいたか女性の憧れの的です。

I'd translate the whole thing as:

> Recently, a man told me: "I watched a commercial and the genetics of your face are the same as Horikita Maki's!! If you work hard on your make-up you can make it where she is". That's a compliment, right?
>
> I told him: "I am thankful for what you said, but I don't look like her at all", but he replied that our genetics are the same...
>
> I don't think it's very important, but please answer.
>
> > That's definitely a great compliment. That's because she's a byword for "cute". How many men cried after marrying? It's the object of admiration of women.

I'm confused whether I'm right because the person who answered doesn't seem to separate their sentences and I can't find anything about "どれほどいたか". I found a text in which it seemed to mean "how many people were there?", but in this case it's written as an embedded question.

With the way I translated, I imagine 'the man who cried" that the person who answered refered to is Horikita Maki's husband. The question was posted in 2015 and Horikita Maki married that year.

I have no idea if he cried at the wedding, but that is the only way to translate that I could think of.

Obviously, my difficulties lie mainly in the reply, but I decided to include the question to provide context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your TL of the question seems okay except for the "**genetics**" part.  「系統{けいとう}が一緒{いっしょ}」 simply means "**You bear a (close) resemblance to (Horikita).**"

Secondly, let me just add ***things*** to the reply to make it the kind of Japanese that should be easier for Japanese-learners.

> それは超ベタ褒めです可愛いの代名詞ですし結婚して
>
> 泣いた男性がドレほどいたか女性の憧れの的です。

will become:

> それは超ベタ褒めです。(堀北真希は)可愛いの代名詞ですし、(堀北が)結婚して
>
> 泣いた男性がドレほどいたか！！(堀北は)女性の憧れの的です。

「どれほどいたか！」＝「たくさんいた！」＝ "How many men there were (who cried!)" = "Many men (cried!)"

**Thus,「どれほどいたか！」 is an exclamation rather than a question.**

> With the way I translated, I imagine 'the man who cried" that the person who answered refered to is Horikita Maki's husband. The question was posted in 2015 and Horikita Maki married that year.

No, it is talking about her male fans who cried when Horikita got married.  "Many men" cried, remember?